# Access-vba copy data Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using access-vba to copy and insert the data into database, many of the data insert successfully, but some data missed. For example, I need to create a new baseline named version 16, and need to copy all the data from version 15 and insert into the same database and same tables under version 16. I have three tables [Baseline],[Sections],[CVELink], and I found the problem is in [CVELink]."runtime error 94, "invalid use of null"," and the debug shows me the problem is on this query

```
             DoCmd.RunSQL sqlStatement
```

I don't know how to fix it. any help would be really appreciate.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code.  It looks like access-vba.  Please fix the tags so the right experts see the question

Comment: @Plutonix thanks, changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. There are null columns in the table, I manage the database and change the code to handle the error if there is null in the database.